# Get IE Version + Add Class to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to find which version of IE people are using and adding a class to the body tag depending on which browser.

the code i have is

```
if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
//Set IE as true
ie = true;
//Create a user agent var
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
//Write a new regEx to find the version number
var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[.0-9]{0,})");
//If the regEx through the userAgent is not null
if (re.exec(ua) != null) {
    //Set the IE version
    ieVersion = parseInt(RegExp.$1);
}


}

else {
    ie = false;
}

function ieTag() {
    if (ie == true) {
        if (ieVersion == 7) {
            $('body').addClass('IE7');
        }
    }
    if (ie == true) {
        if (ieVersion == 8) {
            $('body').addClass('IE8');
        }
    }
    if (ie == true) {
        if (ieVersion == 9) {
            $('body').addClass('IE9');
        }
    }

}
```

and i am using this to call the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //IE Version Control
        ieTag();
    });
</script>
```

but i am only picking up IE 9 for some reason, i have had this script working before so i really dont understand whats gone wrong!!!

i have even tried using this script

```
function ieTag() {
if (ie == true) {
    $('body').addClass('IE' + ieVersion);
}
```

}

but still only picking up IE9

I ma using IE( and the developer tools to change version (which both of these scripts has worked on before)

Comment: Works for IE8, maybe it just doesn't work if you change the version from dev tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason why the js in the question failed in IE 7 and IE 8 was the fact i had included the script using application/javascript rather than text/javascript,

the reason is doesn't work with application/javascript is because this is a new way of including the script that only modern browsers support and older browsers does not support this method, hence IE 7 & 8 failing.

Answer (score 8):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for, but it does seem like the simplest solution:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <body class="ie6">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <body class="ie7">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <body class="ie8">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>         <body class="ie9">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>      <body class="ie10+">  <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->     <body>                <!--<![endif]-->
```

of course added in the HTML where your body tag is supposed to start.

Comment: HTML5Boilerplate does this but on the html tag. Is there a difference or is it just so the code looks a bit cleaner?

Comment: As far as I know it should work just fine on both tags, but rumor has it there is some blocking when used on the body tag that is avoided when the method is used on the html tag instead, so most developers now prefer to use the html tag for this sort of thing, and it is quite common these days.

Comment: im going to go with this option, its not how i planned to do it but works the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could use conditional comments so that it doesn't affect other browsers.

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").addClass("ie-6");
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").addClass("ie-7");
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").addClass("ie-8");
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").addClass("ie-9");
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript for this.

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
  <body class='ie9'>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
  <body class='ie8'>
<![endif]-->
```

etc. For normal browsers you do:

```
<!--[if IE]><!-->
  <body class='normal'>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery you can add ie class to body like this

```
$(function(){
  if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 8) {
    $('body').addClass('ie8');
  }
});
```

Comment: Short note: This won't work in jQuery >= 1.9 unless jQuery Migrate is installed